# Aggregate to 'plain' query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, query-optimization

I have a query which uses aggregate functions to assign the `maximum absolute` of the values to another column in the table. The problem is that it takes whole lot of time (apprx. adds upto 10-15 seconds) to query completion time. This is what the query looks like:

```
UPDATE calculated_table c 
    SET tp = (SELECT MAX(ABS(s.tp)) 
                FROM ts s INNER JOIN tc t ON s.id = t.id
                GROUP BY s.id);
```

Where `id` is not unique, hence the grouping. `tp` is a numeric whole number field. Here is what the tables look like:

```
TABLE ts
       PID(primary)       |            id (FKEY)             |                      tp (integer)                   
--------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------
 1                        | 2                                | -100
 2                        | 2                                | -500
 3                        | 2                                | -1000

TABLE tc
       PID(primary)       |            id (FKEY)                              
--------------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------
 1                        | 2
```

I want the output to look like:

```
TABLE c
       PID(primary)       |         tp (integer)                   
--------------------+-----------------------------+--------
 1                        | 1000
```

I tried to make it work like this:

```
UPDATE calculated_table c 
    SET tp = (SELECT s.tp
                FROM ts s INNER JOIN tc t ON s.id = t.id
                ORDER BY s.tp DESC
                LIMIT 1);
```

Though it improved the performance, however the results are incorrect.. any help would be appreciated?

Comment: can tp be a positive value??

Comment: have you proper inde on c ts id and tc id?

Comment: @MaheshMadushanka yes.. and I have no indexes on id's

Comment: ABS function will cost more so try to get max and min values with this UPDATE calculated_table c 
    SET tp = (SELECT IF (MAX(s.tp) >(Min(s.tp)) * -1,MAX(s.tp),(Min(s.tp)) * -1) AS 
                FROM ts s INNER JOIN tc t ON s.id = t.id
                GROUP BY s.id);

Comment: if it work let me know ill add it as the answer because it will help others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did manage to modify the query, turnsout nesting `aggregate functions` is not a good option. However, if it helps anyone, here is what I ended up doing:

```
UPDATE calculated_table c 
    SET tp = (SELECT ABS(s.trade_position)
                FROM ts s INNER JOIN tc t ON s.id = t.id
                WHERE c.id = s.id
                ORDER BY ABS(s.tp) DESC
                LIMIT 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Though it improved the performance, however the results are incorrect.

*The operation was a success, but the patient died.*

The problem with your query is that

```
SELECT MAX(ABS(s.tp)) 
  FROM ts s INNER JOIN tc t ON s.id = t.id
  GROUP BY s.id);
```

doesn't produce a scalar value; it produces a *column* of values, one for each `s.id`.  Your DBMS really should raise a syntax error.  In terms of performance, I think you're sequentially applying each row produced by the subquery to each row in the target table.  It's probably both slow and wrong.

What you want is to correlate your `select` output with the table you're updating, and limit the rows updated to those correlated.  Here's ANSI syntax to update one table from another:

```
UPDATE calculated_table
SET tp = (SELECT MAX(ABS(s.tp)) 
            FROM ts s INNER JOIN tc t ON s.id = t.id
            where s.id = calculated_table.id)
where exists ( select 1 from ts join tc
               on ts.id = tc.id
               where ts.id = calculated_table.id )
```

That should be close to what you want.

BTW, it's tempting to interpret correlated subqueries literally, to think that the subquery is run *N* times, once for each row in the target table.  And that's the right way to picture it, *logically*.  The DBMS won't implement it that way, though, in all likelihood, and performance should be much better than that picture would suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
UPDATE calculated_table c 
    SET tp = (SELECT greatest( MAX( s.tp ) , - MIN( s.tp ))
                FROM ts s INNER JOIN tc t ON s.id = t.id
                WHERE c.id = s.id
              );
```

Also try to create a multicolumn index on `ts( id, tp )`

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below sql will be helpful to you, I tested in netezza, but not postgresql. Also, I didn't put update on top of it.

SELECT ABS(COM.TP) 
FROM TC C LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT ID,TP 
FROM TS A 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM TS B
          WHERE A.ID = B.ID
           AND ABS(B.TP)>ABS(A.TP))) COM 
ON C.ID = COM.ID